# Yahtzee Php Code 3 of a Kind

Tags: php

```
if($_SESSION['valueofdie1'] != 0 && $_SESSION['valueofdie2'] != 0 && $_SESSION['valueofdie3'] != 0 && $_SESSION['valueofdie4'] != 0 && $_SESSION['valueofdie5'] != 0)
                                            {
                                                if((($_SESSION['valueofdie1'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie2']) && ($_SESSION['valueofdie2'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie3']||$_SESSION['valueofdie4']||$_SESSION['valueofdie5'])) || (($_SESSION['valueofdie1'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie3']) && ($_SESSION['valueofdie3'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie4']||$_SESSION['valueofdie5'])) || (($_SESSION['valueofdie1'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie4']) && ($_SESSION['valueofdie4'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie5'])) 
                                                || (($_SESSION['valueofdie2'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie3']) && ($_SESSION['valueofdie3'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie4']||$_SESSION['valueofdie5'])) || (($_SESSION['valueofdie2'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie4']) && ($_SESSION['valueofdie4'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie5']))
                                                || (($_SESSION['valueofdie3'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie4']) && ($_SESSION['valueofdie4'] == $_SESSION['valueofdie5'])))
                                                {
                                                    if($_POST['choose'] == 'choose 3oaK')
                                                    {
                                                        $_SESSION['g'] = 5;
                                                        $_SESSION['scoretkind'] = $_SESSION['valueofdie1'] + $_SESSION['valueofdie2'] + $_SESSION['valueofdie3'] + $_SESSION['valueofdie4'] + $_SESSION['valueofdie5'];
                                                        unset($_SESSION['3oaKBut']);
                                                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="choose" value="Clear" onLoad="form.submit();">';
                                                        $_POST['sub'] = 'reset';
                                                        $_POST['choose'] = '';
                                                    }

                                                    if(empty($_SESSION['g']))
                                                    {
                                                        $_SESSION['3oaKBut'] = '<input type="submit" name="choose" value="choose 3oaK">';
                                                        echo $_SESSION['3oaKBut'];
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            if($_SESSION['g'] == 5)
                                            {
                                                echo $_SESSION['scoretkind'];
                                            }
```

So here is the code we have. We are trying to check if 3 of the 5 die values are equal. If they are equal we echo out a button that allows the user to choose to score his 3 of a kind, which is the total of all of the dice. Everything works except in some cases the 3 of a kind button would echo out when there isnt a 3 of a kind. Halp PLS

Comment: Advice: Put `$_SESSION['valueofdie1']` and the other dice into an array of values. After that, it should be pretty easy to check how many times each value occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I didn't answer your question by actually solving your bug, but I think your code is hard to read and your approach makes it cumbersome to program all the rules.

General advice: Put `$_SESSION['valueofdie1']` and the other dice into an array of values. That's much easier to work with. After that, it should be pretty easy to check how many times each value occurs. Even when you keep your approach, you could make variables like `$die1`, which is already a lot shorter and more readable than `$_SESSION['valueofdie1']`.

But with an array, you could roughly start like this:

```
// Put all dice into an array.
$dice = array(
  $_SESSION['valueofdie1'],
  $_SESSION['valueofdie2'],
  etc.... );

// Count how many times each die is rolled.
$diceCount = array();
foreach($dice as $die) {
   $count = 0;
   if (isset($diceCount[$die])) {
     $count = $diceCount[$die];
   }

   $diceCount[$die] = $count + 1;
}

// Check possible results simply by looking at those counts.

// If one die value is rolled 5 times, it's Yahtzee...
if (array_search(5, $diceCount) !== false) {
  echo 'Yahtzee!';
}

if (array_search(4, $diceCount) !== false) {
  echo 'Four of a kind';
}

// Full house takes two types.
if (array_search(3, $diceCount) !== false && array_search(2, $diceCount) !== false) {
  echo 'Full house';
} 

for ($diceCount as $die => $count) {
  echo "$count times $die";
}
... etc ...
```

You'll need to expand this list, and take some other rules into account. After all, a Yahtzee could also count as a Four of a Kind. But by checking all those rules, you can generate a new array of possible combinations, which you can check against the previously chosen options. And the outcome of that determines which options the player can choose.

Comment: I would have done a loop on `$_SESSION`: `foreach (array('valueofdie1','valueofdie2','valueofdie3','valueofdie4','valueofdie5','valueofdie6') as $field) { $diceCount[$_SESSION[$field]]++; }`

Comment: Sure. Or even `for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){$diceCount[$_SESSION['valueofdie'.$i]]++;}`